# openssl-net C# simple example

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openssl, openssl-net

I have a C# project and I need to implement a Datagram TLS over UDP for security purposes.

I have researched a lot of libraries and have found this wrapper implementation of OpenSSL library for C# (ManagedOpenSSL) and here is the code [openssl-net](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net).

Unfortunately, I cannot find any reference or example on how to start with using this library since there is no documentation available.

Does anyone know or have any example on how to create a simple client and server implementation using this library in C#? Or any reference to start with..